# MATLAB error: input argument "x" undefined

Tags: matlab

I've got a small MATLAB function I'm attempting to run by calling it from the command line, as follows:

> ??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

For reference, my "main" function:

```
function F = dsr(x)

x(1);
x(2);
x(3);

rho=1.2041;
mu=1.81625e-5;
Re=30;

pref=[10,10,10];
leakagearea=[x(1) x(2) x(3)];

for i=1:3;
 turb(i)=2^0.5*0.6*leakagearea(1,i)*pref(1,i)^((1-2*0.65)/2);
ftrans=mu*Re*leakagearea(1,i)^0.5;
ptrans=(ftrans/(turb(i)*rho^0.5))^(1/0.65);
lam(i)=mu*ftrans/(rho*ptrans);
end;   

input1=[lam(1,1) turb(1,1) 0.65 0.611 10 x(1) 0 0 2 2 2 0];
input2=[lam(1,2) turb(1,2) 0.65 0.611 10 x(2) 0 0 2 2 2 0];
input3=[lam(1,3) turb(1,3) 0.65 0.611 10 x(3) 0 0 2 2 2 0];

airflow=fopen('130109ex1.prj','rt+');
if(airflow==-1);
    errordlg('airflow open Error','Error');
end;


for i=1:11614;
    fid=fgetl(airflow);
       if(strcmp(upper(fid),upper('1 23 plr_leak1 double_door'))==1);
           filepositon=ftell(airflow);
           break;
       end;
    sprintf('다시');
end;
fid=fgetl(airflow);


fseek(airflow,1,'cof');
fprintf(airflow,'%6.5e %5.4f %3.2f %4.3f %d %5.4f %d %d %d %d %d %d\n',input1);
fclose(airflow);

airflow=fopen('130109ex1.prj','rt+');
if(airflow==-1);
    errordlg('airflow open Error','Error');
end;


for i=1:11614;
    fid=fgetl(airflow);
       if(strcmp(upper(fid),upper('2 23 plr_leak1 ev_door'))==1);
           filepositon=ftell(airflow);
           break;
       end;
    sprintf('다시');
end;
fid=fgetl(airflow);


fseek(airflow,1,'cof');
fprintf(airflow,'%6.5e %6.5f %3.2f %3.2f %d %5.4f %d %d %d %d %d %d\n',input2);

fclose(airflow);

airflow=fopen('130109ex1.prj','rt+');
if(airflow==-1);
    errordlg('airflow open Error','Error');
end;


for i=1:11614;
    fid=fgetl(airflow);
       if(strcmp(upper(fid),upper('7 23 plr_leak1 single_door'))==1);
           filepositon=ftell(airflow);
           break;
       end;
    sprintf('다시');
end;
fid=fgetl(airflow);


fseek(airflow,1,'cof');
fprintf(airflow,'%6.5e %6.5f %3.2f %4.3f %d %5.4f %d %d %d %d %d %d\n',input3);


fclose(airflow);

dos('contamx2 130109ex1.prj');
dos('simread_ysm 130109ex1.sim');

output=fopen('130109ex1.lfr','rt');
A=textscan(output, '%s %s %s %s %s %s');
mm=A{1,4};

a0=str2double(mm(84+2,1)); %x1: 1층 외피   (..+2는 왜하는 거지 ?)
a1=str2double(mm(63+2,1)); %x1: 4층 외피 
a2=str2double(mm(35+2,1)); %x1: 8층 외피
a3=str2double(mm(7+2,1)); %x1: 12층 외피

b0=-str2double(mm(85+2,1)); %x2: 1층 계단실문
b1=-str2double(mm(64+2,1)); %x2: 4층 계단실문
b2=-str2double(mm(36+2,1)); %x2: 8층 계단실문
b3=-str2double(mm(8+2,1)); %x2: 12층 계단실문


c0=str2double(mm(87+2,1)); %x3: EV문, 1층
c1=str2double(mm(67+2,1)); %x3: EV문, 4층
c2=str2double(mm(39+2,1)); %x3: EV문, 8층
c3=str2double(mm(11+2,1)); %x3: EV문, 12층


fclose(output);

M=[30 46 38 29 21 19 11 8 -4 -28 -49 27]
S=[a0 a1 a2 a3 b0 b1 b2 b3 c0 c1 c2 c3]

F=(M-S)*(M-S)'


xx=[x(1) x(2) x(3)]
fprintf('%10.9f %10.9f %10.9f',xx)
```

that's all. please help. me

Comment: By which command do you try to call to function? Do you pass `x` like `dsr(x)` or do you simply type `dsr`?

Comment: As already suggested, don't press "run" in the editor, you need to call the function from the command line with an argument, e.g. `dsr([1 2 3])`.